# Why changes ListView background when list item click on android 2.3.3

Tags: android, listview

I have a problem with ListView background on android 2.3.3 (android 4 no problem). When click on list item, changes ListView background to `@color/holo_green` from `android:listSelector` attribute. How to resolve this problem?

my_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="false"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/sa_list_item_selector"
    android:divider="@drawable/sa_list_divider"/>
```

Adding `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` nothing changes

sa_list_item_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/holo_green" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Comment: i also have same problem . you have any solution for this problem.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"><shape><solid color="@color/pressed"></shape></item>
    <item><shape><solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/></shape></item>
</selector>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to change:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/holo_green" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

To:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/holo_green" />
</selector>
```

Look at your selector. The code is there.